# SLAM, How do we know when a robot has completed its mapping process

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a general question about the SLAM process, how do we know once the robot has complete its mapping process? Or is it just a matter of a being satisfied with the representation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213173/slam,-how-do-we-know-when-a-robot-has-completed-its-mapping-process/) by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unless your robot is in an entirely static environment, the mapping process is never finished. Things move, doors open, etc. It's up to you to decide when the map is sufficient for your purposes.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-09**:
Ok that is understandable. But the environment I am working in is completely static. The reason im asking is that I have a requirement to satistfy which says I have to map x in x amount of time, and I need to document the experiment which I need to say when Ill stop the timer, if that makes sense.

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2015-07-09**:
That means you are going to implement an exploration algorithm, right? Let's say you use gmapping. Then, you need to navigate the robot to unknown areas. Comparing the performance of exploration methods does make sense. Otherwise, you are just comparing the proficiency of the human operators.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-10**:
Yes I suppose I would need to implement an exploration algorithm. Im not necessarily measuring the performance of different algorithms but rather just the one I am using. If I implement an exploration algorithm will the algorithm "finish"? Because then I guess that would be answer to my question.

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2015-07-10**:
To finish the mapping process is your choice. You just specify a termination criteria. You will need a metric to do that. You can subscribe to the /map topic and use the ratio `(number of known cells/number of unknown cells)`, for example. Finding a more meaningful metric is up to you.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-10**:
Ok I understand! Thank you very much for the information!

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2015-07-10**:
Sure. I just recommend you to take a look at the exploration packages in ROS, there are a few of them. You can understand their approach by doing so. Here is an example: [explorer](http://wiki.ros.org/explorer)

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-10**:
Thank you very much!